# Powershell Out-Host -paging -or- more to limit output of function

Tags: function, powershell, paging

I have made a function that gives users instructions. When I call it I would like to have only 1 page (screen) of info appear at a time.

I've tried using

```
function1 | Out-Host -paging
```

and

```
function1 | more
```

But neither of them work. The function is a bunch of `Write-Host`s. Do I need to define something within the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out-Host expects a stream of objects and write-host does not do that. It simply writes to the console. Instead, use Write-Output and then try Out-Host -Paging.

Comment: Thanks. That works but I had specified -ForeGroundColor for several lines. Is there a way to do this with Write-Output?

Comment: @user1131196 You can use [Console]::ForegroundColor = "Red" before write-output and after [Console]::ForegroundColor = "Gray" if gray is the default color!

Comment: Thanks Ravikanth and Christian. @Christian Have you been able to get different colours on the same line? I can't seem to find a nonewline equivalent

Comment: @user1131196. It's a little ugly but you can use [Console]::write(), or if script is also used in ISE better $Host.ui.write() and $host.ui.rawui.foregrouncolor or backgroundcolor like with [console]. Maybe some better way to works with text color but I never used in a deep manner.